# Dynamic throttling with reactive extension

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive, reactive-programming

I have a stream of data that initially comes in short bursts and the stream do not stabilize until say after 2 seconds, once the stream has stabilized I'd like to change the throttle period dynamically so any new data that comes is pushed ASAP instead of waiting for the long throttle period.

I was approaching this problem by creating new observable stream that combines a timer and the original data stream (data stream throttled to say 10 ms), where timer ticks and checks if last data has come and how long before previous tick. Once we see less and less data I can then start reducing the timer period so i can push the new stabilized data more frequently.

Is this approach correct or can i better do it? Any pointers or snippet is much appreciated.

Comment: Did you implement your first approach? What problems does it cause to your application?

Comment: It's really not clear what you are asking. Showing a small but complete program demonstrating your initial approach would help. Key facts would help: Is there a maximum data rate that you can handle? If not why not just throttle to that rate? Do you need to "smooth" delivery of burst data, or just throttle it? etc. Dynamic throttling itself is quite easy with Rx - there is a throttle overload that does this by throttling based on a second stream - I presume that is what you have been using.